# Installing Ruby on Rails on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, windows-7

I am in the process of installing Ruby on Rails on windows 7. I installed ruby-1.9.2 (in c:\ruby) and I've installed rails using the `gem install rails` command (doing this from c:\ruby\bin since this is the only place i can call the command). I've then run `rails new my_app` command.

The problem that I have is trying to run the `rails server` command from inside the apps folder (c:\ruby\bin\my_app) I get the message: `'rails' is not recognized...`.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I had to switch from Windows to Ubuntu because on windows all requests in development environment were executing extremely slow. IMHO on ubuntu it is 30x faster for me. If it is possible try ubuntu. It can be installed behind the windows. I very recommend it.

Comment: I've been working on Ubuntu installed on VBox it was very very slow and annoying to use so i decided to try working for a while on windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows you need to set your system PATH variable (My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables -> System variables)

Append the PATH Variable value:: c:\ruby\bin;

Comment: This solved the problem just it needs to be a bit more specific the path at least by me to rails.bat is `c:\ruby\bin\rails.bat` and i added at the end of the existing path in the system variables the above route seperated from the rest of the text already there by a semi-colon, if you can just correct your answer it would be greatly apprecheated

Comment: You should also try this Windows Ruby on Rails installer http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-installer-ruby-and-rails-on-windows-in-a-single-install-4201.html

Comment: No working for me. Neither the comment of "rails.bat"

Comment: My solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35386310/error-trying-to-use-ruby-on-rails/35386650

Answer (score 1):

I'm a windows 7 user, and I was able to get rails working by following this guide:
http://www.wiki.devchix.com/index.php?title=Windows_-_Rails_3
I know linking is frowned upon, but the windows 7 installations is quite detailed, and the devchix guide is excellent.  I store my apps on the desktop in a folder called 'rails' not in the ruby bin.

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you, did you find any problems with using RoR on windows 7?

Comment: There are some annoyances when trying new features, but no real problems.  If I had a mac/linux, I'd use it instead of windows 7 because it seems to be the preferred platform on all the tutorials and add-ons.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Rails For The Windows](http://railsftw.bryanbibat.net/) installer. It allows you install Ruby and Rails on Windows in a very simple way.