# Error trying to use Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It's supposed that I installed Ruby on Rails using RailsInstaller (Windows), but when I try to use the command:

```
rails -v
```

The command prompt shows something like:

> "System can not find the specified path."

I've uninstalled Rails with 'gem' command and reinstall it, but error still alive.

Is there another way to install Ruby on Rails?
How can I solve this problem?

**NOTE:** Ruby\bin is in PATH variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ruby on Rails on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853222/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows)

Comment: I've tried that. It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: installing the previous version of RailsInstaller.

I was trying to use: railsinstaller-3.2.0 (Ruby 2.2.4, Rails 4.2)

It worked good with: railsinstaller-3.1.1 (Ruby 2.1.8, Rails 4.2)

NOTE: I'm using W7 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer on this one. You have to add rails to path.

[Installing Ruby on Rails on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853222/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-windows)

Comment: Ruby is in the PATH, and I can execute 'ruby' command with no problem.
Even, I tried the solutions in comments but It didn't work.

Comment: Worth a shot, but you might have to restart terminal after installing the rails gem. I'm sure you would have done that by now..

Comment: I did that. It didn't work. My solution was to install a previous version of RailsInstaller.

Comment: nice! glad you were able to figure it out!